# Get users base on group and role on Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I want to get all users who have the correct group and role (in a course).

**Pre-condition**: I don't want to write sql query.

Below is my current code, using `course_enrolment_manager` to filter:

```
function get_users_by_group_and_role ($course, $groupid, $roleid) {

    $manager= new course_enrolment_manager($PAGE, $course, null, $roleid, '', $groupid);
    return $manager->get_users('id');
}
```

I don't think this isn't a good solution as the purpose of `course_enrolment_manager` is different from mine. Does anyone know a better method for implementing this?

Comment: Please excuse me asking the obvious question, but why do you not want to write SQL code, when it can get you the answer you need in a fairly straightforward manner?